# Insert layout into another layout

Tags: android, android-layout, layout-inflater

i'm struggling with this problem: I want to create a "whatsapp like" list of conversations and i'd like to bundle image, username and last message in a single external layout that I can call programmatically to then add a new one, but for some reason this doesn't work.

**chat_link_layout.xml**

```
<TextView
    android:text="Username"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/profileimage"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/profileimage"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Medium"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:layout_marginTop="5px"/>

<TextView
    android:text="Last Message"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/lastmessage"
    android:layout_below="@+id/username"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/profileimage"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/profileimage"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Medium"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/profileimage"
    android:layout_marginRight="10px" />
```

**part of the MainActivity.java's onCreate function where i try to call the XML layout**

```
View chatLinkLayout = LayoutInflater.from(getApplication()).inflate(R.layout.chat_link_layout, null);

ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_main);
constraintLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
constraintLayout.addView(chatLinkLayout);
constraintLayout.addView(new CalendarView(getApplicationContext()));
```

the calendar is shown with no problem.

**ChatLinkLayout.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ChatLinkLayout extends FrameLayout {

private TextView username;
private TextView lastmessage;
private ImageView profileimage;

public ChatLinkLayout(Context context) {

        super(context);

        username = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.username);
        lastmessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lastmessage);
        profileimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profileimage);
    }
}
```

Does any of you have any suggestion?

Thank you.

Comment: why don't you use custom listview for that?

Comment: My suggestion would be to learn more about either ArrayAdapter or RecyclerView Adapter. It's not clear why you need to extend FrameLayout

Comment: Use RecyclerView . It will be easy achieving this by RecyclerView.